# Get access to a row from the collection?

Tags: excel, vba, collections, row

I am trying to add all rows from my worksheet in a collection, and then get access to the first cell of the first row - first cell of a first element of my collection. But when I run my macro, I get an error - 424 Object required. I don't understand, what is the problem, could you help me, please?

```
Sub test()
Dim collection1 As New Collection
For Each rw In Rows
If IsEmpty(rw.Cells(1).Value) = False Then
   collection1.Add (rw)
   End If
Next
Cells(1, 2) = collection1.Count - Works correct
Cells(1, 3) = collection1(1).Cells(1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: You are adding the *values* of the cells to the collections, not cell references.

Comment: Try `Cells(1, 3) = collection1(1)(1, 1)`.  Loading an array, not a range, this would be the way of returning the array values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `EntireRow` property of the `rw` variable to assign it to the collection:

```
collection1.Add (rw.EntireRow)
```

Either that, or just remove the brackets from the `Add` statement:

```
collection1.Add rw
```

So the whole code:

```
Sub test()
Dim collection1 As New Collection
For Each rw In Range("A1:A10").Rows
    If IsEmpty(rw.Cells(1).Value) = False Then collection1.Add (rw.EntireRow)
Next
Cells(1, 2) = collection1(1).Cells(1).Value
End Sub
```

The **brackets** are evaluating the `rw` object (which isn't Dimensioned btw) and therefore plugging in the values of it to the collection, instead of the row object itself.

---

Also please note I got rid of the `End If` statement, because you're only doing one action it's easy to get it on one line